# emu kill not working for android 2.0 emulator

Tags: android-emulator

I am successfully able to launch the emulator 2.0 with the new android studio.

```
emulator -version
```

Android emulator version 25.1.6.0

However when I try to kill it it does not do anything and no errors are returned. The command silently fails. Any help is appreciated.

```
adb -s emulator-5554 emu kill
```

Anyone else seen this ? I have couple of workarounds using telnet but was wondering why I am seeing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the release of SDK Tools 25.1.6 commands requires now to authenticate.
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html

Commands need to read the file $HOME/.emulator_console_auth_token and send it before you can send commands.

How to is described here:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210955

Read maybe also how to create an auth-token here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html#console-session